# how to implement video chat in iphone

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, videochat

Can anyone please tell me the way to do video chat in iphone?
I tried to search it on many website but in vain.

I found this link:
http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/iPhone

I am not sure if this works for the video chat too?

Thanks,
Naveed

Comment: did you get any satisfactory result?

Comment: Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13834646/662096

Comment: Check out the iOS Video SDK from Twilio: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/quickstart-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have experience with XMPP, but I think you would have to add your own video solution on top of it. This is definitely not a straightforward task to accomplish - but this might be useful for you:

1) http://code.google.com/p/idoubs/ - open-source 3GPP IMS client for iOS 
2) http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/ - RTMFP protocol - works on iOS when compiled with Adobe AIR 2.6

Best,

-Gabriel